# Latest Projects on front|home page

Tags: 7

I created content type "Project". Added `node--projects.tpl.php`.

And now I need to display latest Projects on my front page WITHOUT Views module???

I need to get a piece of code and put it on my `page--front.tpl.php`. How can I get this code, this loop of my projects?

In WordPress it works very simple, but how does it work in Drupal 7?

Comment: I've posted an answer.Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: To whoever voted to close it: it is not off-topic. It is a valid on-topic question. It shows ultimate lack of own research and unneeded reference to WordPress, true, but that's what downvotes are for, and it already got it's share.

Comment: node--projects.tpl.php is use to alter the display of node of project type. You can display it directly by ticking the "Promoted to front page" option

Answer (score 2):

Check "Promoted to front page" option while creating every node of "Project" type.

[image]

Comment: Ok, I need to get a peace of code and put it on my page--front.tpl.php.

How can I get this code, this loop of my projects?